# dropzonejs with editable ,css classes not getting applied

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dropzone.js

I am trying to add editable inside dropzone ,but editable area is not visible inside dropzone css classes are not getting applied .

```
 <a href="#" editable-text="user.name" onbeforesave='updateUser()'>Hello down</a>
```

you can check in below fiddle. please suggest

**Fiddle::**

http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/1988/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place an "editable" inside a form. It just won't get initialised

Change your `<form></form>` to a `<div></div>` and it should be fine.

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/1989/

Comment: u are right , but i need them below thumbnail . when i aad it with templete previewagain they are not visible and there is no form , u can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/1990/

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are trying to say. 
What do you need under what thumbnail?
What is not visible? What do you mean by "there is no form"?

Comment: sorry ..let me exaplin click on where it says , and file explorer will open where u can select file to upload . once u select file it will create thumbnail for that uploaded image  . i need to put editable text inside that  thumbnail .. hope u understand it now @ http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/1992/

Comment: Actullay i came to know it is not getting applied because they are @JuLo loaded dynamicaly . but how to apply it on dynamic elements

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. 
If you want the editables inside your thumbnails, you'll have to dynamically add them to each thumbnails after they are added.
I'm guessing this would be done in the "success" method inside your dropzone declaration.

Comment: no its inside successfull event , i have added successfully but only problem is if u add editable field dynamically then they dont initialize as editable

Comment: I guess you have to initialise them as editables after you have added them, inside the success function too.